# error : declared as function returning an array in c (mpfr libary)

Tags: c, mpfr

I'm beginner with mpfr, I wrote this program to make a specific calculation and get it like you see,but I don't know why this error appear, this is the most important my code:

```
mpfr_t  myfct(int n)

{
   /......./
        return mpfr_get(result,MPFR_RNDN);

}

int main(void)
{

    mpfr_t U;
    mpfr_set_default_prec (53); 

    mpfr_set_emin (-1073);
    mpfr_set_emax (1024);

    n=10;
    mpfr_init2(U,24);
    mpfr_get(U,my_fct(n),MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_printf ("result: %.40Rg\n", U);

    mpfr_clear(U);

    return 0;
}
```

What's the matter ??

Comment: `my_fct` is different than `myfct`.

Comment: it's just a typing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like GMP types, `mpfr_t` is an array of size 1 (the element is a structure, but you don't really need to know that). If you decide to write a function that returns a MPFR number, you have 2 possibilities (among others):

1. The caller allocates and inits the `mpfr_t` with some given precision. In this case, the `mpfr_t` should be put as an argument of the function, and this is a pointer to this array that is actually passed (according to the rules of the C language). Basically, this can be seen as passing the variable [by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference). MPFR functions use this method.
2. The caller doesn't allocate anything. The prototype of the function should be such that the function returns a pointer `mpfr_ptr` to the structure. So, this function will allocate the `mpfr_t` typically with `malloc` (so that the memory is not freed when the function returns), then init the structure with `mpfr_init2`. The precision may be chosen by this function or passed as an argument.

Note: your program have various typos, but I suppose that this is not the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

`mpfr_t`, just like any other array type, [cannot be used](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.5.3.html) as a return value type; see #1592.

To return a `mpfr_t` value, please follow the convention that all MPFR functions use, and return it through a function parameter.

There is an another error in your code: `mpfr_get()` should return `int` (as per the convention; haven`t actually found such function in MPFR docs), not a `mpfr_t`, see above.